# Why does this abstract static method return None?

Tags: python-3.x, abstract-class

The concrete class doesn't implement `foo()`

```py
import abc

class Base(abc.ABC):

    @staticmethod
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo():
        ...

class Concrete(Base):
    pass

print(Concrete.foo())  # prints "None"
```

I'd expect this to fail with an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that classes defined like:

```py
def foo():
    ...
```

Will return `None` when called.  If I want to communicate "hey you forgot to implement this" on a static method in a context where the caller never creates an object, I need to explicitly raise that error in the base class:

```py
import abc
class Base:

    @staticmethod
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo():
        raise NotImplementedError("subclasses must implement this")

class Concrete(Base):
    pass
```

The expected error **will** show up if the caller attempts to create an object like below.

```py
obj = Concrete()  # TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Concrete with abstract methods foo
```

However, if `Concrete` **does** define `foo()` it will be called instead.